# "Yet" in past perfect tense

Tags: grammar

I've seen "yet" in sentences using the present perfect all the time, but what about the past perfect? Has it ever been used in this tense? Is the following sentence grammatical?

*By 2005, I had not **yet** been introduced to her parents.*

If there is any case where "yet" is deployed in the past perfect, I'd appreciate it if you let me know. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your use of _yet_ is fine, but _In 2005_ would be better than _by_.

Comment: I always thought that we would use the past simple in the case of "in 2005" because the past simple is used to refer to an action happening AT a specific time stamp in the past, while the past perfect refers to an action happening BEFORE the time stamp mentioned. Since _by_ means "not later than/before", I haven't worked out why I can't use it here. Could you elaborate?

Comment: _Yet_ carries the meaning 'by now' or 'by then', so you don't need another 'by'.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is fine.

[Ngram shows that *had not yet been* is fairly common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have_INF+not+yet+been&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) compared to its usage with the present perfect.

A [listing of its usages is shown](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22had%20not%20yet%20been%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en).